# CSS back slash and forward slash in 'calling' out photos from directories

Tags: html, css

This cursor css code that uses back slash for directory generates net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
cursor: url("C:\Users\Ken\projects\JavascriptGames\images\bird.png"), auto;
```

This cursor css code that uses forward slash for directory successfully customizes the cursor

```
cursor: url("C:/Users/Ken/projects/JavascriptGames/images/bird.png"), auto;
```

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because URL syntax is not the same as Windows filepath syntax. The path separator in URLs is `/` (as is the directory seperator character in UNIX and UNIX-like filesystems).

Answer (score 0):

don,t give space between words on the name of images. Becuse the code considers the word or any charactor just after every space as an other folder. That is why image director is changed as ./****\ .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31135862)